# Golang cannot use type as type in argument

Tags: go, interface

I am new to Go language and I am trying to get familiar with interfaces and their assignability.

I am trying to pass an argument from a `struct` into a `function` which is imported from another `package`.

**main.go** package:

```
package main  

import {
  anotherPackage
}

type I1 interface {
  anotherPackage.I2
}

type T1 struct {
  *anotherPackage.S1
}

type T2 struct {
  variable1 T1
}

type T3 struct {
  variable2 T2
}

func handler() {
  var fromI I
  var input = T3{}

  template := fromI.ExportedFunction(input.T3.variable1)
}

func main() {
  handler()
}
```

**anotherPackage.go** package

```
package anotherPackage

type I2 interface {
  ExportedFunction(S1)
}

type S1 struct {
  Path string
  File string
}

type S2 struct {}

func (s2 *S2) ExportedFunction(s1 S1) {}
```

I keep getting an error:

> `cannot use input.T3.variable1 (type T1) as type anotherPackage.S1 in argument to fromI.ExportedFunction`

Comment: You're trying to pass an `T2` to a function which wants a `anotherPackage.S1`.

Comment: If the compiler tells you you cannot do it than you cannot do it. Go is statically typed with no inheritance. You must provide the correct type. So what is the _actual_ question?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that in Go like other Object-oriented language because Go does not support polymorphism. How about using T1 interface as the parameter to ExportedFunction instead of S1.
example
https://play.golang.org/p/72hgbSwNkaS

Comment: "because Go does not support polymorphism" --- go provides (parametric) polymorphism via interfaces.

Comment: @zerkms oh yes!